# How to correctly subtract from total until reaching zero in Swift

Tags: swift

I am creating a fake banking terminal app for learning purposes that is supposed to let a user enter the initial bank account information. Then is able to subtract (withdraw)from the total(balance) and print out the remaining balance. I have been successful this far. Then it's supposed to allow for additional withdraws until the balance reaches zero. It's also not supposed to let you withdraw more than the balance. The problem is when I withdraw additional amounts, instead of subtracting, it adds random numbers. I have been looking at this for 5 hours now and switching code around and trying different things and no luck. Which is why I'm here. I'm stumped and feel pretty dumb because I'm sure it is simple

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

print("How much money is in your bank account?")

if let beginningBalance = readLine() {
    if let balance = Double(beginningBalance) {
        while balance >= 1 {
            print("How much would you like to withdraw?")
            if let withdrawAmount = readLine() {
                if let withdraw = Double(withdrawAmount) {
                    if withdraw > balance {
                        print("Insufficient funds. Please choose a lower amount.")
                    } else {
                        let total = balance - withdraw
                        print("Balance is \(total)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My output so far...

[image: my output]

Comment: I would use recursion

Comment: @ielyamani thanks. That did it. I did try making balance mutable before but didn't remove total from the last else statement. So I ended up reverting back and trying other things until I totally stumped myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `balance` as variable and subtract `withdraw` directly from balance.

```
if let beginningBalance = readLine(),
    var balance = Double(beginningBalance) {
    while balance >= 0.0 {
        print("How much would you like to withdraw?")
        if let withdrawAmount = readLine() {
            if let withdraw = Double(withdrawAmount) {
                if withdraw > balance {
                    print("Insufficient funds. Please choose a lower amount.")
                } else {
                    balance -= withdraw
                    print("Balance is \(balance)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about that. I changed it to 0.00.

Answer (score 1):

I know other people have already answered this one but maybe with some recursion?Also, using a function you'd be able to remove the if let guards.

```
func accountIsEmpty(balance: Double)->Bool {

    balance > 0 ? false : true

}

func withdraw(balance:Double, amount: Double)->Double{

    let isEmpty = accountIsEmpty(balance: balance)
    var newBalance = balance

    print("Your balance is: $\(String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [balance])) before withdraw.")

    if isEmpty {
        return 0
    }

    if amount > balance {
        print("You have insufficent funds")
        print("Deposit $\(String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [balance-amount]).dropFirst()) to affect this transaction.")
        return balance
    }else{
        newBalance -= amount
    }

    print("Balance after withdrawal : \(newBalance).")

    return withdraw(balance: newBalance, amount: amount)
}
```